# React redux-form read value onchange from other component in real time

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/7073llkj

The simple example use the `redux-form-website-template` to show the value, i am very new to react and redux-form, i even dont know what is this, i just wanna read the value very simple in other components.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the props.values.firstName here</div>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the props.values.lastName here</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentOne;
```

Any way or example to show the value very simple in other components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime a `SimpleForm`'s field value is changed, the updated value is kept in the Redux's Store.

In order to get the form's values:

1. First thing you have to do is to connect `ComponentOne` with the Redux's Store, in order to have access to the Form's state.
2. Secondly, you can query the Store and get the `SimpleForm`'s values.

**Something like that:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form'


class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
    const { values } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the values.firstName here</div>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the values.lastName here</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // 2. Secondly, you can query the Store and get the `SimpleForm`'s field value.
  values: getFormValues('simple')(state) || {}
})

// 1. First thing you have to do is to connect `ComponentOne` with the Redux's Store,
// in order to have access to the Form's state, because it's kept in the Store.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentOne)
```

Comment: Cool, now i can get the full object value by {JSON.stringify(values)}, but how can i get the value which i need, for example i need show values.firstName at <h1> tag, i tried {values.firstName } but no luck, thanks

Comment: I get Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined when i tried {values.firstName }, please let me know which step i am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: I understood what's happening. `values` is `undefined` initially, because your form fields are untouched and empty. In order to fix this, you could set a default value to `values`: `values: getFormValues('simple')(state) || {}` . Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxk1y1mrv3

Comment: Thanks!!! this really help me alot, what if i have 100 components need to read the simple form value, i have to made a markup 100 times same as 'ComponentOne' right? Do you know any method to made this more simple to save the time and code?

Comment: You can read about HOC. It could help you in the case you want to reuse a particular flow or solution. However, I would recommend you to start with the [Redux's concepts, motivation and basics](https://redux.js.org/). Would help you much!